# Macbook pro being slowed down ky kernal_tasks in Mavericks

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, memory, google-chrome

I downloaded Mavericks when it first came out and it was no problem. Within the last week or so, my mac has become EXTREMELY slow.

Solutions I have tried:
-Resetting the PRAM/NVRAM
-Resetting the SMC
-Backing up data with time machine and reinstalling Mavericks

Even while running a single chrome web page, I check the Activity Monitor and Kernal_Tasks is using anywhere from 76% to 1,000% cpu usage.

Here is a picture from Activity Monitor where Kernal_Tasks is using 76% cpu usage: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2ustudc&s=8

Here is a picture from Activity Monitor where Kernal_Tasks is using over 1,000% cpu usage: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2zycrva&s=8#.U_0kTbxdUjw

Keep in mind, these images were taken only while running a few pages in Chrome. I've searched around and a lot of people are having this problem, but there aren't really solutions going around.

EDIT: My internet is really fast, there's something wrong with my computer I think.

Please someone help me :(

Here is my EtreCheck:

EtreCheck version: 1.9.15 (52)
Report generated August 26, 2014 at 4:57:26 PM PDT

Hardware Information: ?
    MacBook Pro (13-inch, Late 2011) (Verified)
    MacBook Pro - model: MacBookPro8,1
    1 2.4 GHz Intel Core i5 CPU: 2 cores
    4 GB RAM

Video Information: ?
    Intel HD Graphics 3000 - VRAM: 384 MB
        Color LCD 1280 x 800

System Software: ?
    OS X 10.9.4 (13E28) - Uptime: 0 days 0:53:41

Disk Information: ?
    ST9500325ASG disk0 : (500.11 GB)
    S.M.A.R.T. Status: Verified
        EFI (disk0s1) : 209.7 MB 
        Macintosh HD (disk0s2) / [Startup]: 499.25 GB (143.88 GB free)
        Recovery HD (disk0s3) : 650 MB

```
MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-8A8
```

USB Information: ?
    Apple Computer, Inc. IR Receiver 
    Apple Inc. FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in) 
    Apple Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad 
    Apple Inc. BRCM2070 Hub 
        Apple Inc. Bluetooth USB Host Controller

Thunderbolt Information: ?
    Apple Inc. thunderbolt_bus

Configuration files: ?
    /etc/hosts - Count: 15

Gatekeeper: ?
    Mac App Store and identified developers

Kernel Extensions: ?
    [loaded]    com.digidesign.iokit.DigiDal (8.0.3f1) Support
    [loaded]    com.digidesign.iokit.DigiIO (8.0.3f1) Support
    [not loaded]    com.digidesign.usb.elevenrack.driver (1.0.1) Support
    [not loaded]    com.focusrite.driver.usb2audio (1.1) Support
    [not loaded]    com.paceap.kext.pacesupport.leopard (5.9 - SDK 10.4) Support
    [not loaded]    com.paceap.kext.pacesupport.master (5.9 - SDK 10.6) Support
    [not loaded]    com.paceap.kext.pacesupport.panther (5.9 - SDK 10.3) Support
    [loaded]    com.paceap.kext.pacesupport.snowleopard (5.9 - SDK 10.6) Support
    [not loaded]    com.paceap.kext.pacesupport.tiger (5.9 - SDK 10.4) Support
    [loaded]    net.telestream.driver.TelestreamAudio (1.0.5 - SDK 10.6) Support

Startup Items: ?
    DigidesignLoader: Path: /Library/StartupItems/DigidesignLoader
    PACESupport: Path: /Library/StartupItems/PACESupport

Launch Daemons: ?
    [loaded]    com.adobe.fpsaud.plist Support
    [loaded]    com.adobe.SwitchBoard.plist Support
    [running]   com.flipvideo.FlipShareServer.launchd.plist Support
    [loaded]    com.google.keystone.daemon.plist Support
    [running]   com.iobit.AMCDaemon.plist Support
    [running]   com.paceap.eden.licensed.plist Support
    [loaded]    PACESupport.plist Support

Launch Agents: ?
    [not loaded]    com.adobe.AAM.Updater-1.0.plist Support
    [running]   com.flipvideo.FlipShare.AutoRun.plist Support
    [loaded]    com.google.keystone.agent.plist Support
    [running]   SBA_ListenerAgent.plist Support

User Launch Agents: ?
    [loaded]    ca.madefresh.BodegaAgent.plist Support
    [not loaded]    com.google.keystone.agent.plist Support
    [loaded]    com.macpaw.CleanMyMac.helperTool.plist Support
    [loaded]    com.macpaw.CleanMyMac.trashSizeWatcher.plist Support
    [loaded]    com.macpaw.CleanMyMac.volumeWatcher.plist Support
    [not loaded]    com.user.UninstallAD.plist Support
    [loaded]    com.valvesoftware.steamclean.plist Support
    [failed]    net.infinite-labs.PlugSuit.Agent.plist Support

User Login Items: ?
    Google Chrome

Internet Plug-ins: ?
    Flip4Mac WMV Plugin: Version: 2.4.4.2 Support
    FlashPlayer-10.6: Version: 12.0.0.38 - SDK 10.6 Support
    Default Browser: Version: 537 - SDK 10.9
    Flash Player: Version: 12.0.0.38 - SDK 10.6 Outdated! Update
    QuickTime Plugin: Version: 7.7.3
    o1dbrowserplugin: Version: 5.4.2.18903 Support
    googletalkbrowserplugin: Version: 5.4.2.18903 Support
    Silverlight: Version: 5.1.30317.0 - SDK 10.6 Support
    Unity Web Player: Version: UnityPlayer version 4.3.7f1 - SDK 10.6 Support
    JavaAppletPlugin: Version: Java 7 Update 17 Check version

Safari Extensions: ?
    Searchme-2 
    Ebay Shopping Assistant 
    Amazon Shopping Assistant 
    AllMyTube 
    Slick Savings

Audio Plug-ins: ?
    BluetoothAudioPlugIn: Version: 1.0 - SDK 10.9
    AirPlay: Version: 2.0 - SDK 10.9
    AppleAVBAudio: Version: 203.2 - SDK 10.9
    iSightAudio: Version: 7.7.3 - SDK 10.9

iTunes Plug-ins: ?
    Quartz Composer Visualizer: Version: 1.4 - SDK 10.9

User iTunes Plug-ins ?
    TuneUp Visualizer: Version: 2.4.0 - SDK 10.6 Support

User Internet Plug-ins ?
    RealPlayer Plugin: Version: Unknown

3rd Party Preference Panes: ?
    Flash Player  Support

Time Machine: ?
    Skip System Files: NO
    Mobile backups: ON
    Auto backup: YES
    Volumes being backed up:
        Macintosh HD: Disk size: 464.96 GB Disk used: 330.96 GB
    Destinations:
        Stefan Music:T [Local] (Last used)
        Total size: 0 B 
        Total number of backups: (null) 
        Size of backup disk: Too small
            Backup size 0 B < (Disk used 330.96 GB X 3)
        Untitled [Local] 
        Total size: 232.57 GB 
        Total number of backups: 2 
        Oldest backup: 2014-08-23 11:18:43 +0000 
        Last backup: 2014-08-23 18:41:48 +0000 
        Size of backup disk: Too small
            Backup size 232.57 GB < (Disk used 330.96 GB X 3)
    Time Machine details may not be accurate.
    All volumes being backed up may not be listed.

Top Processes by CPU: ?
        12% WindowServer
         8% QuickTime Player
         1% hidd
         1% Google Chrome
         0% SystemUIServer

Top Processes by Memory: ?
    295 MB  helpd
    156 MB  com.apple.IconServicesAgent
    131 MB  Google Chrome
    106 MB  Finder
    90 MB   mds_stores

Virtual Memory Information: ?
    940 MB  Free RAM
    1.60 GB Active RAM
    505 MB  Inactive RAM
    1013 MB Wired RAM
    663 MB  Page-ins
    0 B Page-outs

Answer (score 1):

> com.macpaw.CleanMyMac.helperTool.plist Support [loaded]
>   com.macpaw.CleanMyMac.trashSizeWatcher.plist Support [loaded]
>   com.macpaw.CleanMyMac.volumeWatcher.plist Support [not loaded]
>   The above is probably the main cause of your problems. Google for directions to uninstall CleanMyMac.

Also get rid of the following:

> [not loaded]    com.paceap.kext.pacesupport.leopard (5.9.1 - SDK 10.4)
>   Support
>       [not loaded]    com.paceap.kext.pacesupport.master (5.9.1 - SDK 10.6) Support
>       [not loaded]    com.paceap.kext.pacesupport.panther (5.9.1 - SDK 10.3) Support
>       [loaded]    com.paceap.kext.pacesupport.snowleopard (5.9.1 - SDK 10.6) Support
>       [not loaded]    com.paceap.kext.pacesupport.tiger (5.9.1 - SDK 10.4) Support